# Capistrano: How to disable "try_sudo" from a task

Tags: capistrano

I'm currently using capistrano for deploy scripts. I'm working in a constrained environment where sudo does not have certain permissions, namely to create symlinks. The capistrano task create_symlink calls try_sudo by default. Is there a way I can add a condition to the task so that try_sudo is ignored?

Comment: Did you figure out a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this by

```
 set :use_sudo, false
```

Comment: and how should I do this on a task level? if I do "task :create_symlink, use_sudo: false" it will expect a block.

Comment: I don't know how to do it on a task level. I know how to do it either globally or locally on a new task I define, but not on an existing specific task (ok, maybe a namespace, but that doesn't help me in the case)

Comment: what exactly your use case?

Comment: sudo doesn't have permission to create the symlink. But sudo starts services. So, sudo is allowed to "restart", but not to "create_symlink"